# Tint VectorDrawable inside Drawable Resource xml

Tags: android, android-resources, tint, android-vectordrawable

i've had a drawable resource for a selectable Button/ImageView like this:

```
<selector>
<item android:state_selected="true">
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="@color/blue"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <bitmap
                android:src="@drawable/ic_icon"
                android:tint="@color/white"/>

        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
<item>
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="@color/background_unselected"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <bitmap
                android:src="@drawable/ic_icon"
                android:tint="@color/icon_unselected"/>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
```

as i've switched to use VectorDrawables the above declaration does not work because i cannot reference a VectorDrawable with a `<bitmap>` tag.
But as far as i know that's the only way i can tint the icon.

I also cannot apply a Colorfilter in code as this would tint the whole drawable and not just the icon.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can define colors as attributes and reference them in your SVG. Then can load the drawable styled by a theme.

Short example:

**attributes.xml**

```
<declare-styleable name="vectorColors">
    <attr name="primaryColor" format="color" />
    <attr name="secondaryColor" format="color" />
</declare-styleable>
```

**ic_icon.xml**

```
<path
    android:fillColor="?attr/primaryColor"
    android:pathData="...." />
<path
    android:fillColor="?attr/secondaryColor"
    android:pathData="...." />
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="svgColors">
    <item name="primaryColor">@color/someColor</item> 
    <!-- also can use #RRGGBB way -->
    <item name="secondaryColor">#ff0000</item>
</style>
```

Then load your theme and drawable:

```
Resources.Theme theme = getResources().newTheme();
theme.applyStyle(R.style.svgColors, false);
VectorDrawableCompat drawable = VectorDrawableCompat.create(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_icon, theme);
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

In your specific selector you should replace

```
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/ic_icon"
        android:tint="@color/white"/>
</item>
```

by `<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_icon">`

[Reference and full example](https://medium.com/@emmaguy/dynamically-changing-svg-colours-on-android-b026a99137ad)

Comment: Nope. They don't. The solution is not valid.

Comment: Well it is working through the code. My case was to change vector white paths to another color according to current theme. I did: 1. declared field `<attr name="vectorWhite" format="reference|color"/>` 2. added attr to my main theme `<item name="vectorWhite">@color/colorForThisTheme</item>` 3. called from code to get drawable knowing it's resource id by `Drawable drawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, drawableId);` 3. loaded image (at my case) by Glide.

Comment: IMHO the key is to use drawable respecting current theme - I used `AppCompatResources `which itself finds what's theme now.

Comment: This doesn't work, <bitmap> requires bitmap drawable, this crashes with XmlPullParserException "<bitmap> requires a valid 'src' attribute"